# echo $(echo $HOM) in eshell of win10 platform get void function reported

Tags: microsoft-windows, eshell

I am working on emacs-27.1 of windows 10.

```
PS C:\Users\gaowei> emacs.exe --version
GNU Emacs 27.1
```

Within the eshell, I tried:

```
~/.doom.d [master] λ which echo
eshell/echo is a compiled Lisp function in ‘em-basic.el’.

~/.doom.d [master] λ echo $HOME
C:\Users\gaowei
```

It works properly until I run to nest the commands as:

```
~/.doom.d [master] λ echo $(echo $HOM)
Symbol’s function definition is void: echo
```

What's the problem? echo does exist in eshell but report void function.

Answer (score 1):

That's syntax of eshell [eshell documentation](http://hhttps://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Expansion) which  is intended to be an alternative to the IELM.
So `()` is designed for elisp functions to distinguish commands.

```
λ (sqrt 11)
3.3166247903554
```

on the other hand, curly brackets are designed for commands:

```
λ echo ${echo $HOME}
C:\Users\me
```